# How to convert date to the format in which date is saved in MongoDB using Java and Spring?

Tags: java, mongodb, date-formatting

```
 @GetMapping("/{dateFrom}/{dateTo}")
       public List<com.example.demo.attendance> getRange(@PathVariable("dateFrom")  String dateFrom,@PathVariable("dateTo") String dateTo) throws ParseException{
          Date date1= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'").parse(dateFrom);
          Date date2= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'").parse(dateTo);
          System.out.println(date1);
          System.out.println(date2);
           List<com.example.demo.attendance> att =  this.attRepo.findDateBetween(date1,date2);

           return att;
        }
```

here i am trying tho convert the date in the format (yyyy-MM-dd) to the format in which date is saved in mongodb to perform queries

Comment: don't put screenshot  write your original code in the question ..

Comment: edited @Ironman

Comment: as looking your code..your not trying to save `Date` in database

Comment: While it’s not 100 % clear to me what you are asking, I dare say similar questions have been asked and answered often before. Did you search? Always a good idea before asking. If you searched and found answers that weren’t sufficient for solving your issue, please explain in detail what it is you are still missing, and we can guide you much more precisely.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting ISO 8601-compliant String to java.util.Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso-8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion date parameters should be rather passed as request parameters but anyway. Why don't you do this instead:

```
@GetMapping("/{dateFrom}/{dateTo}")
public List < com.example.demo.attendance > getRange(@PathVariable("dateFrom") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") Date fromDate, 
  @PathVariable("dateTo") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") Date dateTo) throws ParseException {
    System.out.println(date1);
    System.out.println(date2);
    List < com.example.demo.attendance > att = this.attRepo.findDateBetween(date1, date2);

    return att;
}
```

Currently MongoDB driver supports only `java.util.Date`
I don't know which version of MongoDB Java Driver you use but here is the [Documentation of the driver’s support for BSON document representations](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/bson/documents/) for 3.4. You can keep up-to-date in case something changes. Here to find the latest documentation for the [MongoDB Java Driver](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/)